# How to properly configure http tag in Spring Security 3.1?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have problem with my `spring-security.xml` file. I have wanted to configure some session settings and first of all create login form to maintain guests and logged in users.

This is my `spring-security.xml` headline:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```

As you can see I am using Spring Security in latest version - 3.1. When I try to change the schema versione to lower, I have got errors. In terms of 3.1 version I have only yellow warnings in Eclipse.

My `http` tag looks like:

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>      
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/wellcome*" access="ROLE_USER"  />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/wellcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"  />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/invalidsession" />
</security:http>
```

And at the first line of this tag I have long list of warnings:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Method 'setAuthenticationEntryPoint' is marked deprecated [config set: SpringMVC/web-context]
- Method 'setSessionAuthenticationStrategy' is marked deprecated [config set: SpringMVC/web-
 context]
- Method 'setUserAttribute' is marked deprecated [config set: SpringMVC/web-context]
- Method 'setRequestCache' is marked deprecated [config set: SpringMVC/web-context]
- Method 'setKey' is marked deprecated [config set: SpringMVC/web-context]
- Method 'setSecurityContextRepository' is marked deprecated [config set: SpringMVC/web-context]
```

Additionaly I have also one warning on the third line:

```
Method 'setLoginFormUrl' is marked deprecated [config set: SpringMVC/web-context]
```

Could you explain me how I should properly define my `spring-security.xml` file with `http` tag in Spring Security 3.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** This issue is now fixed in Spring Security 3.1.2, so if you're using 3.1 or 3.1.1, please upgrade it to newer version.

**Original answer:**

Your config is fine. It's [a known bug in Spring Security with STS in Eclipse](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1909) (see also forum topic mentioned there in *Reference URL*).

For now you can ignore the warnings, login on https://jira.springsource.org and vote up the issue and wait until it's fixed (or remove spring nature for your project if you can't stand those warnings).

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" use-expressions="true"> 
        <form-login login-processing-url="/login"
            login-page="/login.html"
            default-target-url='/index.html'
            always-use-default-target='true'
/>

<logout logout-url="/logout" />
```

Comment: The warnings are still the same.